# Bypassing XSS filters

Tags: xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New XSS cheatsheet?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/164/new-xss-cheatsheet)

Can anyone give me list of ways to encode XSS payload , or to be precise what are the ways to encode XSS payload to bypass encoding of <> or ().
I know about double encoding bypass with %253c and Unicode , but I want to know all methods available. Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% certain I understand the intent of your question. It sounds to me like you're trying to obtain a listing of potential ways to circumvent XSS protection. If this is not the case you should re-word your question to reflect your intent. This community is not here to provide ways to exploit.

Comment: My question is what type of encoding can by used to encode XSS payload and fire up XSS alert, I don't want to exploit anything , I just started learning about XSS , and I went over rsnakes XSS list and new HTML5 XSS vectors , it's just that I want to know , what encoding techniques are used to encode XSS vector. If you could post list of encoding techniques..Thanks

Comment: See also: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/164/new-xss-cheatsheet

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would be a wise idea to give how-to's on XSS attacks; though many resources exist e.g. Ch. 12 of the WAHH on XSS.

The best way to prevent XSS attacks is to substitute every special character used in these attacks (e.g., `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`,`'`  with their html character equivalent `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&quot;`, `&#39;`) for all user-provided text and only allowing users to markup their comments using a limited non-html markup language (like markdown) that only gets substituted into a safe subset of html at the last step of processing.  (Also be careful their comments never get executed in any sort of javascript processing  you wrote).

If you choose to ignore this, and only sanitizing specific tags (like `<script>`, `<object>`, `javascript` check the sanitation is being done recursively (so `<scr<script>ipt>` doesn't become `<script>` after a single-pass sanitation), is case/white-space insensitive, and only stops when the last complete sanitation attempt did not change the input.  In python something like

```
import re
def sanitation_single_pass(user_input):
    pattern = re.compile('<[^>]*(script|object|meta|style)[^>]*>', re.IGNORECASE) 
    # this is very quick sample regex that could appear in a sanitation routine
    # not meant to be inclusive of most XSS threats;
    # e.g. this doesn't prevent having javascript in links or img src, etc.
    return pattern.sub('', user_input)


def sanitation(user_input):
    processed_user_input = sanitation_single_pass(user_input)
    while processed_user_input != user_input:
        user_input = processed_user_input
        processed_user_input = sanitation_single_pass(user_input)
    return processed_user_input
```

Also pay attention to encoding issues, make sure you define a charset (`<meta charset="utf-8">` at the top of your html templates) and that you force user input into this encoding before sanitization.  Also try to recognize that some browsers will interpret things like `java&#x0A;script` as `javascript` (`&#x0A;` is a line break), etc.

Comment: Fun note for the day: PHP's `strip_tags` method (which is what I normally use as part of my XSS cleaning) already does this recursive cleaning for you.  Quite convenient, although it makes it easy to forget if you ever need to drop something else in instead.

Answer (score 0):

XSS Cheat Sheet, never leave home without it - http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Though obviously this should be used to protect yourself and not for malicious intent. The community is here to teach and learn from each other methods of IT Security, not to provide unauthorized access methods.

Comment: I'm not 'hacker' , and too lazy for cookie stealing etc... My goal is reporting XSS vuln to sites like Google of FB, cos of the money...